# angular ngrx store update array item if id matches

Tags: angular, typescript, ngrx, store

I have array of calls. They have different keywords, and call has id which is call_id. Array is empty on begining. If array is empty or there is no call with incoming call id, then it have to add call to call array in state. In otherwise, when array in state has a call with incoming id, it will update matched call. Now initialState.calls[] is still empty

```
 export interface Call {
  timestamp: number;
  call_id: string;
  keywords: Keyword[];
}

 export const initialState: KeywordsModel = {
   version: '',
   calls: [],
   isOpen: false,
   lastUpdatedOn: Date.now()
 };

 export const reducer = createReducer(
   initialState,
   on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.messageReceived, (state, { message, timeReceived }) => ({
     ...state,
     ...message,
     lastUpdatedOn: timeReceived
   })),
   on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.keywordsPageOpened, state => ({ ...state, isOpen: true })),
   on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.messageCallReceived, (state, { call }) => ({ ...state, calls: (state.calls.map((existCall: Call) => (existCall.call_id === call.call_id) ? state.calls[existCall.call_id] : [...state.calls, call])),
  }),
  
  ))
 
 export function reducerFactory(state: KeywordsModel | null, actions: Action) {
   return reducer(state, actions);
 }
```

After `messageCallReceived` with map() is done STATE remains empty `{}`.

Please for hints.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exacly sure about what you wanted to achieve, but most likely correct code would be this:

```
state.calls.map((existCall: Call) => (existCall.call_id === call.call_id) ? call: existCall)
```

this should update only one item in your array

Edit: full logic with update, and if none was updated - push new item

```
on(KeywordsWebSocketActions.messageCallReceived, (state, { call }) => {
   let wasUpdated = false;
   const newCalls = state.calls.map(c => {
      if( c.call_id == call.call_id) {
         wasUpdated = true;
         return call;
      } else {
         return c;
      }
   })
   if(!wasUpdated){
      newCalls.push(call);
   }
   return {
     ...state,
     calls: newCalls,
   }
})
```

Comment: I have array of calls. They have different keywords, and call has id which is call_id. Array is empty on begining. If array is empty or there is no call with incoming call id, then it have to add call to call array in state. In otherwise, when array in state has a call with incoming id, it will update matched call. Now initialState.calls[] is still empty :(

Comment: please give me more clarification.

Comment: ah, I see. this code will just replace the corresponding item. I ll update the answer with logic on how to add items, if none found